# regex on url cannot split out hash without GET param

Tags: javascript, regex

I have almost managed to acheive what i am aiming for: A function that checks for a valid url then returns its parts. A valid url may well be schema-less or protocol-less (this is used both front end listening to a textarea and back end parsing results from a scraped url and its tags).

Here is the working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/6v1u5w1f/2/

```js
var url = {
check:function( url ){
 var urlPattern = /((http|ftp|https):)?\/\/[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+([\w.,@?^=%&amp;:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&amp;\/~+#-])?/gi;
 var patt = new RegExp( urlPattern );
 return patt.exec( url );
},
getParts: function( url ){
 url = this.check( url );
    if( !url ) return false;
    var singleUrlPattern =/^(?:(.*?):)?(\/\/)?(?:[^\/\.]+\.)*?([^\/\.]+)\.?([^\/]*)(?:([^?]*)?(?:\?([^#]*))?)?(.*)?/;
      return singleUrlPattern.exec( url[0] );
    }
};


var urls = {
 schema_less: '//cartassets.s3.amazonaws.com/img/636/nl_nbp.jpg',
 http:    'http://cartassets.s3.amazonaws.com/img/636/nl_nbp.jpg',
 https:   'https://cartassets.s3.amazonaws.com/img/636/nl_nbp.jpg',
 get:    'https://cartassets.s3.amazonaws.com/img/636/nl_nbp.jpg?this=that',
 hash:    'https://cartassets.s3.amazonaws.com/img/636/nl_nbp.jpg#this=that',
 getAndHash:  'https://cartassets.s3.amazonaws.com/img/636/nl_nbp.jpg?this=that#dogs=cats',
 none:    'cartassets.s3.amazonaws.com/img/636/nl_nbp.jpg',
 sentence:  'bob https://cartassets.s3.amazonaws.com/img/636/nl_nbp.jpg dog',
 barUrl:   'hi there this is my url: mazonaws.com/img/636/nl_nbp.jpg' };

//loop each url and run through the getParts function and print what it returns
for( var keya in urls ){
  console.log( keya+':' );
  console.log( url.getParts( urls[keya] ) );
  console.log( '               ' );    
}
```

In the example it will loop through a series of poss url patterns and console log the results of the function.

The issue is with a hash only in the url, I cannot get it to split out the hash from the path of the url. When there is a GET param it is find but not just a hash..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking into account what you've already tried and the scope of your question, you can use the following expression to match URLs:

```
(?:(https?|ftp):\/\/)?\/*([^:\/\s]+)((\/\w+)*\/)([-.\w]+[^#?\s]*)?(?:\?([^#\s]*))?(#[-\w@?^=%&;\/~+#]+)?
```

[Test online and read the explanation pane on the right](https://regex101.com/r/mD3pP7/2)

*Disclaimer: this regex does have some false positives, matching about anything with a "`/`", because URIs are not quite different from any word in a text. Also, it does not cover all valid URIs. It is only intended as an approach to what the OP stated.*

**However**, if you're trying to parse the URL, regex is not the tool for that. The browser already does that. Check the following code:

```js
var urls = {
  schema_less: '//cartassets.s3.amazonaws.com/img/636/nl_nbp.jpg',
  http:   'http://cartassets.s3.amazonaws.com/img/636/nl_nbp.jpg',
  https:   'https://cartassets.s3.amazonaws.com/img/636/nl_nbp.jpg',
  get:    'https://cartassets.s3.amazonaws.com/img/636/nl_nbp.jpg?this=that',
  hash:   'https://cartassets.s3.amazonaws.com/img/636/nl_nbp.jpg#this=that',
  getAndHash: 'https://cartassets.s3.amazonaws.com/img/636/nl_nbp.jpg?this=that#dogs=cats',
  none:   'cartassets.s3.amazonaws.com/img/636/nl_nbp.jpg',
};

var parseURL = document.createElement('a');

for( var keya in urls ){
  parseURL.href = urls[keya];
  ['href','protocol','host','hostname','port','pathname','search','hash'].forEach( function(part) {
    document.write("<br />", keya , ": ", part, ": ", parseURL[part]);
  });
}
```